# Зачем вообще нужен модификатор virtual в c#?

Tags: c#, virtual

Ну в общем такой вопрос, зачем нужен модификатор virtual? В чем заключается его особенность, необходимость в использовании? Почему нельзя просто переопределять не виртуальные методы?
Спасибо заранее!

Comment: "Вот! Вот вопрос. Вы же наповал меня бьёте этим вопросом." Братья Вайнеры

Comment: [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/9fkccyh4.aspx).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Для реализации полиморфизма. Допустим мы имеем два класса:

```
public class Parent
{
    public void Func()
    {
        ...
    }
}

public class Child : Parent
{
    public void Func()
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

И имеем использование

```
Paren obj = new Child();
obj.Func();
```

Если мы не имеем модификатора virtual (в языке), то мы ставим перед компилятором неразрешимую задачу - какую из функций (Parent.Func() или Child.Func()) использовать. При наличие же такого модификатора в языке его наличие перед определением функции укажет компилятору использовать вариант из наследника (полиморфизм), а отсутствие вариант из родительского класса.

Но почему бы не использовать всегда какой то один вариант? Тогда virtual не нужен. Но тогда для доступа ко второму варианту придется использовать какие то дополнительные средства, например приведение типов, ссылки и т.д. Либо существенно ограничивать разработчиков в средствах выражения.

Answer (score 1):

Ключевое слово **virtual** используется для изменения объявлений методов, свойств, индексаторов и событий и разрешения их переопределения в производном классе. 
Значит в классах наследниках ты можешь либо переопредлить метод добавив к функции слово **override** либо оставить ее, но тогда при вызове функции у тебя вызовется реализация родительского класса.